# ElasticSearch Multi Type Search using Java API or Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to Search My Index in all Types and all fields for the query.
I know how to do it using REST way.
I want to know how to do it using JAVA API and  more specifically in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

This is some code i have written but seams to be pretty messed in terms of return Type.

```
@Override
public Page<Object> searchInAll(String searchQuery) {

    MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder =QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all", "trump");
    SearchQuery searchQueryFinal = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchQueryBuilder).withIndices("booksearchserver").withTypes("authors","books").build();

    return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQueryFinal, Author.class, new SearchResultMapper(){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        public <T> FacetedPage<T> mapResults(SearchResponse response, Class<T> clazz, Pageable pageable) {

            long totalHits = response.getHits().getTotalHits();
            List<Book> content = new ArrayList<Book>();
            for (SearchHit searchHit : response.getHits()) {
                if (response.getHits().getHits().length <= 0) {
                    return null;
                }else if(searchHit.getType().equals("books")){
                    logger.info("Creating Book,Mapping Book,Adding Book to Page");
                }
                else if(searchHit.getType().equals("author")){
                    logger.info("Creating Author,Mapping Author,Adding Author to Page");
                }
                logger.info(searchHit.getType());
            }

            List<FacetResult> facets = new ArrayList<FacetResult>();
            if (response.getFacets() != null) {
                for (Facet facet : response.getFacets()) {
                    FacetResult facetResult = DefaultFacetMapper.parse(facet);
                    if (facetResult != null) {
                        facets.add(facetResult);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new FacetedPageImpl<T>((List<T>)content, pageable, totalHits, facets);

        }
    });
```